# Mathematical Induction on Fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction

I have ben stuck on this for a while.

Let $F(N)$ be the Fibonacci numbers with $F(1)=F(2)=1$. Show that $4(-1)^n + 5(F(N))^2$ is a square for all integers $N$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Presumably the exponent should be $N$, not $n$.  They are not the same, though are often related.  Have you done the base case?  Then assume it is true up to $k$, plug in $k+1$ and play with what you get.  Plug in the definition of $F(N+1)$.  What happens?

Comment: I did check the base case byt I dont know how to prove it using My hypothesis

Comment: Numerically, it looks like the square root of your expression satisfies the Fibonacci recursion, with $s_1=1,s_2=3$.  I'd try to prove that inductively.

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked and answered here before (but the closest I could find is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032275/induction-proof-of-fibonacci-number which isn't quite the same thing).

Comment: @lulu For reference, that sequence is known as the Lucas numbers $L_n$ [A000204](https://oeis.org/A000032). So one evidently wants to show that $L_n =5F_n^2+4(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Semiclassical  Thanks.  I've seen references to the Lucas numbers, but never looked them up.  Apparently this connection to Fibonacci is well known, though it is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't prove it inductively, so if you specifically need an inductive proof, this wouldn't work.

Instead, this uses the closed form for the Fibonacci sequence, which is that $F(N)=\dfrac{\alpha^N-\beta^N}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{-1}{\alpha}$.

The expression $4\cdot(-1)^N+5(F(N))^2$ becomes 
$$4\cdot(-1)^N+5\left(\dfrac{\alpha^N-\beta^N}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2
=4\cdot(-1)^N+\alpha^{2N}-2\alpha^N\beta^{N}+\beta^{2N}.$$

Since $\beta=\frac{-1}{\alpha}$, $2\alpha^N\beta^N=2\cdot(-1)^N$ and so our expression becomes $$\begin{align}
4\cdot(-1)^N+\alpha^{2N}-2(-1)^{N}+\beta^{2N}= \\
\alpha^{2N}+2(-1)^N+\beta^{2N}= \\
\alpha^{2N}+2\alpha^N\beta^N+\beta^{2N}= \\
(\alpha^N+\beta^N)^2
\end{align}$$ which is a perfect square.